Transform parquet table file by file
I have a big parquet table stored in multiple partitions, and each partition having multiple files inside of it, like:
s3
├── gender=M
│   ├── age=10
│   │   ├── part-000.parquet
│   │   ├── part-001.parquet
│   │   └── part-002.parquet
│   └── age=20
│       ├── part-000.parquet
│       ├── part-001.parquet
│       └── part-002.parquet
└── gender=W
    ├── age=10
    │   ├── part-000.parquet
    │   ├── part-001.parquet
    │   └── part-002.parquet
    └── age=20
        ├── part-000.parquet
        ├── part-001.parquet
        └── part-002.parquet

I want to apply transformations in some columns of the data. These transformations will not change schema/dimensions of the table, nor will they depend on data "outside" of the current row (for example a transformation could be one that concatenates a certain prefix to the values of a string column).
Since the partitions can be very large, my approach is to apply this transformations on each parquet file separately and then overwrite the original parquet files with the transformed ones. In pseudo-code, it goes like this:
for each .parquet file, do the following:
(taking as example the file s3://gender=M/age=10/part-000.parquet)
move the file to a temporary location:
's3://gender=M/age=10/part-000.parquet' ⟼ 's3://tmp/gender=M/age=10/part-000.parquet'

use spark to read from temporary location and transform it:
df = spark.read.parquet('s3://tmp/gender=M/age=10/part-000.parquet')
transformed_df = transform(df)

use spark to write the transformed file to a new temporary location:
transformed_df.coalesce(1).write.parquet('s3://tmp/transformed/gender=M/age=10/')
# this will create a file with a different name, for example s3://tmp/transformed/gender=M/age=10/part-xyz.parquet

move transformed file to original location, with original file name:
's3://tmp/transformed/gender=M/age=10/part-xyz.parquet' ⟼ 's3://gender=M/age=10/part-000.parquet'

remove s3://tmp/
After testing this approach, it looks like the resulting data is correct, but I don't know to which extents it won't cause problems in future use of the data. Is it problematic to do something like this? In terms of metadata of the table, do I lose anything by doing so?
Edit:
One additional information worth mentioning is that none of the transformations needs filtering the data, and all of them are done with mapInArrow, which I believe have similar characteristics to using standard udfs, so they are not intrinsically taking advantage of spark's parallelization across executors.

How often would you do this? Is this a one-time thing or do you plan to have this scheduled? Because as a one-time thing, it should be fine, but if you plan to schedule this, it is not the best way to do it. Why not take care of this before exporting (do the transformations in a filter, then combine the results)?

For now it's a one-time thing but the routine should be available for future use. What drawbacks do you see? I'm trying to make the process the most "modular" as possible, in order to mitigate the problems related to lack of resources (for example combining all the results might not fit into a single execution)

by most “modular” I mean most granular

You could just read that parquet file, use a checkpoint, and overwrite the parquet again, but my concern is more about what does this help out exactly? How does reading a single parquet file help? You are not guaranteed that you will always get the data you are interested in. I understand that you don't want to 'scan' all the input data, but by reading a single parquet, you are not guaranteed that you will get X data, you still need to do a scan and filter. What is your use case?

"You are not guaranteed that you will always get the data you are interested in" - can you explain why that's the case? I don't think I'd need to use any filter since I'm interested in applying the transformation on every row (I'll add this detail to the question) for the given file. I've also added a new information on question edit's that might support the approach I'm taking. Thanks for the help by the way

I recently had an issue with this so: ensure that the schema is consistent after the transformations. Refresh the table metadata after transformations if using Hive.

@Memristor which type of issue did you have?

@leo.b. Java error after saving a table locally, it said that the schema on save for the dataframe used was not same as the schema of the table. At the end I had to remove some session configurations.

Thanks for clarifying. You were doing the same process of rewriting each parquet file one by one, and then when you tried to save the entire table it failed?

@vilalabinot could you elaborate more on why the data I load might not be the correct one? If that's the case then I'm absolutely not doing it this way.

Sorry for the delayed response; if you read the specific parquet file, you will be assured that gender is M and age is 10, but it's hard to predict what other columns will contain (the values). Basically, how do you know that the first partition contains the data that you want? This is conceptually out of Spark's idea and you should not move in this direction. What prevents you from doing the transformations before you export? Spark should not be exploited for such manual use cases; I think that something has gone wrong earlier when you are at this thinking point.

When it comes to the cons, the first thing is that you might end up with a schema that is not compatible with the rest of the parquet files, the second thing is that you will end up utilizing only one core in your cluster because you are reading a single parquet file (unless you repartition manually which defeats the purpose - because you will have a lot of small files)...

@vilalabinot thanks for your insights. I agree that it is conceptually out of Spark's idea, in the sense that I'll be doing some of the logic (splitting the execution) that Spark can be responsible for. I think the main reason for me is to have more control of a better granulated data. The transformations using mapInArrow make the Spark executor OOM pretty easily, so handling partitions of, let's say 200GB size at once, is a big leap compared to handling 200 1GB parquet files one by one, running any verification I need including of course the equality of schema.

@vilalabinot Regarding the point you made about not knowing that the partition has the data I want, I don't see it as a problem because I'm transforming all of the data (column-wise) available without doing any prior filter.
